# Android Настройки сети, разрешить внешнее сетевое подключение

Tags: android, сеть

При вызове функции `socket.connect(ip, port);` в отладчике сообщение `"The application is running"`, в консоли `"NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default"`.
Добавил в ресурсы `res/xml` файл `network_security_config.xml`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true" />
</network-security-config>
```

И в манифест в тег `application` добавил:

```
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
```

Теперь в консоли сообщение `"NetworkSecurityConfig: Using Network Security Config from resource network_security_config debugBuild: true"`

Как решить эту проблему?

Answer (score 0):

Для начала, нужно в manifest.xml выдать разрешение для работы с сетью:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Второе, убедитесь, что вы работаете с сетью не в главном потоке, т.к. работа с сетью блокирует поток, а в правилах андроид, блокировать главный поток нельзя.